# Will SignedUrl Of An Object in GCP be valid after updating the object?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

- A file is uploaded by user to a bucket in GCP , signed URL of the
  object is created .
- After which server edits the file and updates
  as  the  same object .

Will the signed url generated previously be valid ?

Comment: I found that it gets invalid , as access token gets revoked (as of my idea of how it is) . But is there any way to make it prevail :) ?